# How to replace all links from string

Tags: php

Recently I've started to write some php so I'm still  a newbie and maybe this is a very simple question, excuse me if that is the case because I couldn't find any solution to this problem.

I have this piece of code which I expected to replace all youtube links to iframes and the rest of url to normal links, but it doesnt seems to work and I can't find what is wrong.

```
        <?php
            if (strpos($text[$i], 'youtube.com') !== false) {
                 $text[$i] = preg_replace('/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i','<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src="http://youtube.com/embed/$1\" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $text[$i]);
            } else {
                 $text[$i] = preg_replace('#(\A|[^=\]\'"a-zA-Z0-9])(http[s]?://(.+?)/[^()<>\s]+)#i', '\\1<a target="_blank" href="\\2">\\3</a>', $text[$i]);
            } ?>
<div class="post">
    <?php print $author[$i]; ?>
    <?php print $time[$i]; ?>
    <?php print $text[$i]; ?>
</div>
```

*$text[$i]* returns different text records on a sql database.

Is possible to replace all urls with iframes and links this or some other way?
Thank you in advice.

Comment: What does it do? What is `text[$i]`?

Comment: @chris85 this code reuturns the posts from a sql database. `$text[$i]`  returns the values of the row text at the database.

Comment: Without the literal value of `text[$i]` we cant really help. Also note characters only need to be in a character class once and the `.` in a character class doesnt need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Going on the assumption that the value of `$text[$i]` is a standard `www.youtube.com/watch=v?` link, it looks like you've combined some .htaccess with PHP. If you're intending this

> ```
> <iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/$1\">
> ```

to load something in place of `$1\`, it won't work because `$1\` is recognized as part of the string instead of a variable. You need to strip out the string after `watch=v?`, store it in `$needle` (or whatever you want), then `src="http://youtube.com/embed/'.$needle.'"`

**1.** The quick and dirty solution:

```
<?php
        if (strpos($text[$i], 'youtube.com') !== false) {
             $needle = explode("watch=v?",$text[$i]);
             $text[$i] = str_replace($text[$i], '<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src="http://youtube.com/embed/'.$needle[1].'" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $text[$i]);
        }
?>
```

Exploding (creating an array from a delimited string) splits the `$text[$i]` into `$needle` making `$needle[1] = "youtube-video-id"`. This is why `$needle[1]` is used in the `<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/'.$needle[1].'">`

This won't get you JUST the video ID though. `$needle[1]` is whatever came after `watch=v?`in `$text[$i]` so bear that in mind.

ETA: You can take it a step further and keep the http or https of `$text[$i]` by using `$needle[0]` which contains the string "https://www.youtube.com/". **NOTE:** this will throw a cross-site scripting error if your site is https and the iframe src is http.

```
$text[$i] = str_replace($text[$i], '<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src="'.$needle[0].'embed/'.$needle[1].'" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $text[$i]);
```

**2.** The better solution:

Assuming the link is the usual `https://www.youtube.com/watch=v?asdf1234` you can replace `watch=v?` with `embed/`

```
<?php
    if (strpos($text[$i], 'youtube.com') !== false) {
         $needle = str_replace("watch=v?","embed/",$text[$i]);
         $text[$i] = str_replace($text[$i], '<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src="'.$needle.'" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $text[$i]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but how could I store the ID of the video then?

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation as to why certain things are done. Remember, it's a quick and dirty solution and may require tweaking.